# How to squish a continuous cosine-theta score to a discrete (0/1) output?

Tags: machine-learning, softmax, sigmoid

I implemented a cosine-theta function, which calculates the relation between two articles. If two articles are very similar then the words should contain quite some overlap. However, a cosine theta score of 0.54 does not mean "related" or "not related". I should end up with a definitive answer which is either 0 for 'not related' or 1 for 'related'.

I know that there are sigmoid and softmax functions, yet I should find the optimal parameters to give to such functions and I do not know if these functions are satisfactory solutions. I was thinking that I have the cosine theta score, I can calculate the percentage of overlap between two sentences two (e.g. the amount of overlapping words divided by the amount of words in the article) and maybe some more interesting things. Then with the data, I could maybe write a function (what type of function I do not know and is part of the question!), after which I can minimize the error via the SciPy library. This means that I should do some sort of supervised learning, and I am willing to label article pairs with labels (0/1) in order to train a network. Is this worth the effort?

```
        # Count words of two strings.
        v1, v2 = self.word_count(s1), self.word_count(s2)
        # Calculate the intersection of the words in both strings.
        v3 = set(v1.keys()) & set(v2.keys())

        # Calculate some sort of ratio between the overlap and the
        # article length (since 1 overlapping word on 2 words is more important
        # then 4 overlapping words on articles of 492 words).
        p = min(len(v1), len(v2)) / len(v3)

        numerator = sum([v1[w] * v2[w] for w in v3])

        w1 = sum([v1[w]**2 for w in v1.keys()])
        w2 = sum([v2[w]**2 for w in v2.keys()])

        denominator = math.sqrt(w1) * math.sqrt(w2)

        # Calculate the cosine similarity
        if not denominator:
            return 0.0
        else:
            return (float(numerator) / denominator)
```

As said, I would like to use variables such as p, and the cosine theta score in order to produce an accurate discrete binary label, either 0 or 1.

Answer (score 2):

> As said, I would like to use variables such as p, and the cosine theta score in order to produce an accurate discrete binary label, either 0 or 1.

Here it really comes down to what you mean by accuracy. It is up to you to choose how the overlap affects whether or not two strings are "matching" unless you have a labelled data set. If you have a labelled data set (I.e., a set of pairs of strings along with a 0 or 1 label), then you can train a binary classification algorithm and try to optimise based on that. I would recommend something like a neural net or SVM due to the potentially high dimensional, categorical nature of your problem.

Even the optimisation, however, is a subjective measure. For example, in theory let's pretend you have a model which out of 100 samples only predicts 1 answer (Giving 99 unknowns). Technically if that one answer is correct, that is a model with 100% accuracy, but which has a very low *recall*. Generally in machine learning you will find a trade off between recall and accuracy.

Some people like to go for certain metrics which combine the two (The most famous of which is the [F1 score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F1_score)), but honestly it depends on the application. If I have a marketing campaign with a fixed budget, then I care more about accuracy - I would only want to target consumers who are likely to buy my product. If however, we are looking to test for a deadly disease or markers for bank fraud, then it's feasible for that test to be accurate only 10% of the time - if its recall of true positives is somewhere close to 100%.

Finally, if you have no labelled data, then your best bet is just to define some cut off value which you believe indicates a good match. This is would then be more analogous to a binary clustering problem, and you could use some more abstract measure such as distance to a centroid to test which cluster (Either the "related" or "unrelated" cluster) the point belongs to. Note however that here your features feel like they would be incredibly hard to define.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to explain that in such depth. It’s really kind. I will definitely look into SVM and Neural Nets. Although I was sceptical about Neural Nets because of 2 reasons being that: 1. The input nodes would consist out of an arbitrary length of 2 sentenced split into words. I think that such net would have a hard time to ‘understand’ that we are comparing two sentences. 2) input nodes are assigned weights, yet these nodes are just ‘random’ words (due to the nature of sentences). So learning a mapping by means of weights seems odd to me.  Either way; thank you a lot!